# Kendo, How do you bind MVVM text: fields to a remote DataSource?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, single-page-application

I have an example of this working for local values defined in the viewmodel (observable) class constructor, but it does not seem to work when you have a remote datasource.

http://jsfiddle.net/hbuNP/7/

How could I get an example similar to the one below working for remote datasources, is it even possible?

```html
<div id='root'>
    <label>Remote Name: </label> 
    <span data-bind="text: firstName"><!--firstName--></span>, 
    <span data-bind="text: lastName"><!--lastName--></span>

    <div>
        <label>Remote Name: 
            <input data-bind="value: firstName" />,
            <input data-bind="value: lastName" />
        </label> 
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id='local-root'>
    <label>Local Name: </label>
    <span data-bind="text: firstName"></span>, 
    <span data-bind="text: lastName"></span>

    <div>
        <label>Local Name: 
            <input data-bind="value: firstName" />,
            <input data-bind="value: lastName" />
        </label> 
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id='test-ajax'>
    <pre>
    </pre>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    /**
    * #local-root example, binds to local data like in the examples
    */
    var personLocalViewModel = kendo.observable({
        firstName: 'James',
        lastName: 'Taylor'
    });

    kendo.bind($('#local-root'), personLocalViewModel);

    /** 
    * set's up a mock api endpoint for jquery and other libraries
    */
    $.mockjax({
        url: "js/data/person.json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        responseText: {
            firstName: 'James',
            lastName: 'Taylor'
        }
    });

    /**
    * test-ajax - proves mockajax works
    */
    $.ajax({
        url: "js/data/person.json",
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(response){
            $('#test-ajax pre').text(JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });


    /**
    * #root or remote-root, this dataSource is not bidning to the html, why?
    */
    console.log('KENDO.js', kendo.data);
    var personSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "js/data/person.json",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema:{
            parse: function(response){
                console.log('personSource.schema.parse',response);
                return response;
            },
            data: function(response){
                console.log('personSource.schema.data',response);
                return response;
            }
        }
    });

    //would this work?
    var personViewModel = kendo.observable({
        dataSource: personSource
    });

    //would this work?
    var personViewModel2 = kendo.observable(personSource);

    kendo.bind($('#root'), personViewModel);


});
```

Comment: Did you have any luck with my solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DataSource expects to operate on a collection of records. I'm sure you can get around that with parse or schema but for this example I changed the mock ajax call to return an array.

```
$.mockjax({
    url: "js/data/person.json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    responseText: [{
        firstName: 'James',
        lastName: 'Taylor'
    }]
});
```

The first problem is that you setup the datasource but never populate the data. I added a call to `.read()`

```
personSource.read();
```

As I changed the responseText to an array, I updated your bindings similar to this:

```
data-bind="text: dataSource.view()[0].firstName"
```

Lastly, [here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbuNP/10/)

Comment: I also have been talking to Telerik, and they advised that this method is not officially supported and that javascript in bindings may not be supported in the future.  Unfortunately they also do not have a 'better' solution for this specific case.  They advised using a tightly coupled variant between the datasource and the observable object which.... does not allow you to share the remote datasource between viewmodels.